# List Item is being ignored while migration

Tags: list, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Sorry if this question had been solved earlier.

I have got a simple code to make things understandable

```
public class Treatment
{
       public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<string> Issue { get; set; }
        public List<string> Medicine { get; set; }
        public List<string> Test { get; set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set;     
}
```

After Add-Migrationa and Update-Database

The design of the table is like this-

```
[dbo].[Treatments](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Doctor_Id] [int] NULL ForeignKey,
[Patient_Id] [int] NULL ForeignKey
```

what happened to list items like Medicine,Test etc.

By the way, I am working on EF6.